# Only one worker seems to be prcoessing jobs in Gearman

Tags: php, gearman

I am running distributed job distribution through gearman. I am trying to convert 1000 pdf files of size 10 MB each. I am able to set it up and get the pdf files encoded.

I have the following code:

gearman_client.php (only to initialize)

```
<?php

class gearman_client{

    static $timeout = 5000;

    private static function addServerToCLient($client, $server){

        $added = 0;
        $client->setTimeout(self::$timeout);

        $server = explode(':', $server);

        $job_server = $server[0];
        if(array_key_exists(1, $server))
            $job_server_port = $server[1];
        else 
            $job_server_port = 4730; //default port

        try{
            $added = $client->addServer($job_server, $job_server_port); 
        }
        catch(GearmanException $e){
            error_log(sprintf("GearmanException: %s .Error adding Gearman Server: %s, port: %s",$e->getMessage(), $job_server, $job_server_port), false);
        }
        return $added;
    }

    public static function initialize(){

        $client = null;

        $servers = explode(',', GEARMAN_JOB_SERVERS);
        $added = 0;

        //To accomodate Gearman bug
        $flag = 0;
        foreach($servers as $server){
            if(!$flag){
                unset($client);
                $client = new GearmanClient();
            }

            $added = self::addServerToCLient($client, $server); 
            if($added)
                $flag = 1;  
        }

        if($flag)
            return  $client;
        return 0;

    }

}
```

Gearman client

```
$gmclient = gearman_client::initialize();
      if(!$gmclient){
        $this->error("Gearman server error","Could not create a gearman client object with a running Gearman Server");
        return;
      }
      $pdfdata = array(
            "id_host" => $this->id_host,
            "id_vhost" => $this->id_vhost,
            "id_contents" => $id_contents
            );
      $job_handle = $gmclient->doBackground("pdf_convert", json_encode($pdfdata));

      if ($gmclient->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS){
        error_log("Gearman client: Bad Return code. Error while submitting background job");
      }
```

Gearman worker

```
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer("192.0.1.118");

$worker->addFunction("pdf_convert", function(GearmanJob $job) {

    $workload = json_decode($job->workload());
    $id_host = $workload->id_host;
    $id_vhost = $workload->id_vhost;
    $id_contents = $workload->id_contents;

    contents_path($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents);
    pdf($id_host, $id_vhost, $id_contents);

    // You would then, of course, actually call this:
    //mail($workload->email, $workload->subject, $workload->body);
});

while ($worker->work());
```

everything seems to be working well.  However, I see that even though I start multiple instances of gearman worker, there is only one worker which is always busy(which I can see through the telnet interface).

If I introduce a `sleep(30)` in the worker code, then I start to see other workers taking up jobs.

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: It seems to be working OK. Apparently, the jobs were submitted at a much lower pace than the pace pf pdf processing. That is why I almost always saw only one worker busy. As I mentioned before, if I use sleep, I can see multiple workers busy.